# Why does a session variable have to be serializable?

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications, servlet-3.0

When trying to store a List variable of custom objects
`session.setAttribute` is complaining that’s the variable is not serializable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your entire servlet session can be serialized to disk or another store at any moment. So all objects in it must be serializable.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have explained, the purpose of requiring session variables to be serializable is that this allows the container framework to use object serialization to:

- migrate sessions between server instances in a distributed web service implementation
- persist sessions over server restarts, or to save memory.

But the interesting thing is that the Servlet 3.0 specification doesn't actually require this.  Instead it says:

> ### 7.7.2 Distributed Environments
>
> Within an application marked as distributable, all requests that are
>   part of a session  must be handled by one JVM at a time. The container
>   must be able to handle all  objects placed into instances of the
>   `HttpSession` class using the `setAttribute` or `putValue` methods
>   appropriately. The following restrictions are imposed to meet  these
>   conditions:
>
> - The container must accept objects that implement the `Serializable` interface.
> - The container may choose to support storage of other designat ed objects in the  `HttpSession`, such as references to Enterprise
>     JavaBeans components and  transactions.
> - Migration of sessions will be handled by container-specific facilities. The distributed servlet container must throw an 
>     `IllegalArgumentException` for objects where the container cannot
>     support the mechanism necessary for migration of the session storing
>     them. The distributed servlet container must support the mechanism
>     necessary for migrating objects that implement `Serializable`.
>
> These restrictions mean that the Developer is ensured that there are
>   no additional  concurrency issues beyond those encountered in a
>   non-distributed container.  The Container Provider can ensure
>   scalability and quality of service features like  load-balancing and
>   failover by having the ability to move a session object, and its 
>   contents, from any active node of the distributed system to a
>   different node of the  system.

If we parse this carefully, it is saying that:

- A *distributed* container *must* support object serialization as one way of migrating objects in a session.
- An application doesn't need to be marked as distributable.
- A container doesn't need to be a distributed container.
- A container *may* support other means of migrating the objects.

So what does this mean?  Well I think it means that the apparent requirement that your sessions objects implement `Serializable` is stemming from your choice of container AND the way that you have chosen to implement the webapp.  Hypothetically you could change those choices.

Answer (score 0):

The servlet container (your application server, like Tomcat) might want to store the session information to disk. This will help you retain user sessions when the server is restarted, and also allows it to manage memory more efficiently if it doesn't store every session object in memory, but just looks it up when needed.

So your session objects need to be `Serializable`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to access the model in different request scope, you need to store it in http session. According to the requirement of JPA entity class, which is
involved in http session, has to implement the  Serializable interface.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31031619)